# SharePoint Farm feature not deploying to all members

Tags: development, solution-package, timer-jobs

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm solution (with some timer jobs tied to SPTimerV4 and a LockType of None) that is not deploying it's GAC'ed DLL to all servers in the farm.  This timer job must run on each server individually in order to access the SecurityTokenService web.config.

The package type is set to "WebFrontEnd", however most of the members of this farm do not run the Web Foundation service -- when using WFE, the GAC'ed DLL only makes it to WFEs, of course.  If the package is set to "ApplicationServer", none of the features are activated even though the GAC'ed DLL does make it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working.  I put my timer job in a separate VS project that was ApplicationServer scoped with the feature, then referenced the feature in a Package from a project that was WFE scoped.